# cps in "yet another haskell turorial"

Tags: haskell

I'm learning haskell by reading the book "Yet Another Haskell Tutorial", and I encounter a problem when comes to the contiuation passing style. The book gives a  cps fold like:

```
cfold’ f z [] = z
cfold’ f z (x:xs) = f x z (\y -> cfold’ f y xs)
```

and gives the test result:

```
CPS> cfold (+) 0 [1,2,3,4]
10
CPS> cfold (:) [] [1,2,3]
[1,2,3]
```

but, when I try to test this, I find there is a problem, the ghci gives:

```
*Main> cfold (+) 0 []

<interactive>:8:7:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
      t10 = (t10 -> t10) -> t10
    Expected type: t10 -> t10 -> (t10 -> t10) -> t10
      Actual type: t10 -> t10 -> t10
    In the first argument of `cfold', namely `(+)'
    In the expression: cfold (+) 0 []
    In an equation for `it': it = cfold (+) 0 []
```

It makes sense to me, so I change the definition of cps to something like
this:

```
cfold f z [] = z
cfold f z (x:xs) = (\y -> cfold f y xs) (f x z)
```

And it works fine:

```
*Main> cfold (+) 0 [1,2,3]
6
```

So my question comes, is it a bug in the book or something I miss here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there is an error in the book. The function `cfold'` in the book takes a function in contiuation passing style, so the function you pass to `cfold'` has to take 3 arguments: the accumulator, the current list element and the continuation, to which to pass the result.

`(+)` takes only two arguments, as it's not in cps style, so you can't use the cfold' function. To sum the elements of a list using cfold', you would write:

```
> cfold' (\e acc cont -> cont (acc + e)) 0 [3,2,4]
9
```

Notice that the lambda takes *three* arguments: The element, the accumulator and the continuation. The continuation is a function that says "what to do next", given the result of the current computation. So by calling the continuation each time, you process the next element.

So, what do you think happens when I don't call the continuation? Can I maybe stop processing the list that way, to implement something like takeWhile?

```
> cfold' (\acc e cont -> if e <= 3 then cont (e : acc) else acc) [] [1,2..]
[3,2,1]
```

In this example, we don't call the continuation when the element is greater than 3, so we stop processing of the list. Otherwise, we prepend the element to the accumulator, that's why the list comes out in reverse. As the example demonstrates, this works fine with infinite lists.

And, you can also write a function that transforms *any* 2-argument function that is not in cps style to cps style:

```
toCps2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b -> (c -> d) -> d)
toCps2 f = \a b c -> c (f a b)
```

This function just passes the result of applying the non-cps function to the continuation. You can use this function to implement your cfold, which takes a function that is not in cps style to fold a list:

```
cfold :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> [a] -> c
cfold f = cfold' (toCps2 f)
```

With this function, you can now use (+) to fold your list:

```
> cfold (+) 0 [3,2,4]
9
```

Answer (score 2):

In the *Yet Another Haskell Tutorial* is also a definition of *cfold*

```
cfold f z l = cfold' (\x t g -> f x (g t)) z l
```

This function *cfold* is using *cfold'*

In the WinHugs-environment it is working OK.